# C# Insert text from one txt file to another txt file

Tags: c#, text, insert

I would like to insert text from one text file to another.

So for example I have a text file at C:\Users\Public\Test1.txt

```css
first
second
third
forth
```

And i have a second text file at C:\Users\Public\Test2.txt

```css
1
2
3
4
```

I want to insert Test2.txt into Test1.txt

The end result should be:

```css
first
second
1
2
3
4
third
forth
```

It should be inserted at the third line.

So far I have this:

```
string strTextFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\test1.txt";
int iInsertAtLineNumber = 2;
string strTextToInsert = @"C:\Users\Public\test2.txt";
ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(
    strTextFileName);
string line;
while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    lines.Add(line);
rdr.Close();
if (lines.Count > iInsertAtLineNumber)
    lines.Insert(iInsertAtLineNumber,
       strTextToInsert);
else
    lines.Add(strTextToInsert);
StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(
    strTextFileName);
foreach (string strNewLine in lines)
    wrtr.WriteLine(strNewLine);
wrtr.Close();
```

However I get this when i run it:

```css
first
second
C:\Users\Public\test2.txt
third
forth
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're inserting (once) strTextToInsert, not its content (lines.Add(strTextToInsert);)

Comment: You aren't actually reading the second file, just inserting the file name into the first file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `StreamReaders`/`Writers`, you can use methods from the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helper class.

```
const string textFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\test1.txt";
const string textToInsertFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\test2.txt";
const int insertAtLineNumber = 2;

List<string> fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(textFileName).ToList();
fileContent.InsertRange(insertAtLineNumber , File.ReadAllLines(textToInsertFileName));

File.WriteAllLines(textFileName, fileContent);
```

A `List<string>` is way more convenient than an `ArrayList`. I also renamed a couple of your variables (most notably `textToInsertFileName`, and removed the prefix cluttering your declarations, any modern IDE will tell you the datatype if you hover for half a second) and declared your constants with `const`.

---

Your original problem was related to the fact that you're never reading from `strTextToInsert`, looks like you thought it was already the text to insert where it's actually the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your structure or types around too much you could create a method to read the lines

```
public ArrayList GetFileLines(string fileName)
{
    var lines = new ArrayList();
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            lines.Add(line);
    }
    return lines;
}
```

In the intiial question you were not reading the second file, in the following example it is a little easier to determine when you are reading the files and that each one is read:

```
string strTextFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\test1.txt";
int iInsertAtLineNumber = 2;
string strTextToInsert = @"C:\Users\Public\test2.txt";
ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();

lines.AddRange(GetFileLines(strTextFileName));

lines.InsertRange(iInsertAtLineNumber, GetFileLines(strTextToInsert));

using (var wrtr = new StreamWriter(strTextFileName))
{
    foreach (string strNewLine in lines)
        wrtr.WriteLine(strNewLine);
}
```

NOTE: if you wrap a reader or write in a using statement it will automatically close

I haven't tested this and it could be done better, but hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction. This solution would completely rewrite the first file